# Pass php var or string to java. Android Studio

Tags: java, php, android

I'm not really sure how to do go about passing a variable from PHP to Java. I'd like to do the business logic in Java. I'd like to pass a variable $result from the PHP script dupCreateAccount.php.

```
<?php
require "db.php";
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultName) > 0 || mysqli_num_rows($resultEmail) > 0)
{
    $result = "ex";
}
else
{
    $result = "b";
}

if( count_chars($password) < 6)
{
    $result = "bP";
}

echo (string) $result;
?>
```

This the php code. When I echo the results I can see the strings when running the android emulator.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
    String type = voids[3];
    String checkUsername_url = "http://localhost/dupCreateAccount.php";
    if(type.equals("Validate"))
    {
        try {
            String user = voids[0];
            String email = voids[1];
            String password = voids [2];
            URL url = new URL(checkUsername_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
            httpConn.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_date = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode(user,"UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            buffWriter.write(post_date);
            buffWriter.flush();
            buffWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line;

            while((line = bf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result += line;
            }
            bf.close();
            is.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();

            return result;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(result.equals("b"))
            result = "bad username or email";
        if(result.equals("bP"))
            result = "bad password";

        alert.setMessage(result + " on Crack Execute here");
        alert.show();
    }
```

What I was thinking was that when I return the variable result in PHP it gets sent too the OnPostExecute method. But I don't that's right. I'm not sure what step I'm missing .

EDIT: So the php result gets passed to java. But the problem i'm having is messing with the String result after it's passed. In the OnPostExecute method the equals method doesn't do anything.

Comment: FYI it's "Java", not "JAVA" or "java". (It's also "PHP", not "php".)

Comment: That wasn't helpful at all man.

Comment: I'm not answering your question (otherwise I'd post an answer). But this stuff is important in our industry. Attention to detail, man.

Comment: Agreed, so is logic and context clues.

Comment: You have a lot of code in your question. Sometimes this is necessary, however, answerers will find you question much more approachable if you can distill your example code into only necessary components for the question.

Comment: It seems you miss the **?** between **.php** and **user=** ... and you don't need to URLEncode ASCII chars, I mean the parameters name

Comment: @Greenstick thank you, I just don't know exactly where in my code I should be focusing on. I'm new to app development.

Comment: @LluisFelisart I don't believe there is any problem with the syntax of my PHP code nor the Java code as it seems to be working as intended.

Comment: No worries! I'm no Java programmer and haven't worked with PHP for 5 years. That said, generally speaking, passing variables between two languages is done through some form of data exchange language / spec. You may want to search for examples of passing data from PHP to Java using JSON or XML.